# How to free memory at end of PHP script to make my database insertion script faster for the next request?

Tags: php, mysql, xml, performance

I have a PHP script that reads the contents of an XML file and then creates an object using

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($file_name, 0, TRUE);
```

It then converts the object to a workable array and loops through the array and saves the data to a database.  I've noticed that when I am using this script over and over again, even thought the XML files are roughly the same size the script takes longer and longer.

Do I need to free up some memory, or are there any good practices I can do when I've reached the end of a memory intensive script?

Comment: PHP does not keep any state between requests. If the script takes longer each time then some external (to PHP) factor is causing it.

Comment: Turning SimpleXMLElement into an Array is most likely not necessary at all, but even though, would not cause your problem most likely. What differs is the amount of data you've got already in your database. So unless you provide any specifics about your database and the code that inserts the data, all that can be said is that you don't ask in a way to give you useful directions. Only that SimpleXMLElement and memory used by PHP *most likely* is not the issue.

Answer (score 2):

First thing I'd check is the database structure. It might be you need to drop/add some indexes in the database tables. It could be stuff is slowing down because the database is slowing down, exposing the weak spots in the database.

You need to metric your script. Echo out the time before and after the database queries. Check how much time is spent individually and in total and how much on the lines containing the queries.

So at the beginning and end of the script , as well as just before and just after the query lines , do:

```
echo microtime(), "<br />\n";
```

If this is not the problem (and that would actually really surprise me), then you can check if you are perhaps storing too much data to (for example) session or so.

Comment: If database access is slow for `INSERT` (or `UPDATE` for that matter) queries the solution is to drop unnecessary indices, not to create more, that would only make it even slower ;)

Comment: @ScallioXTX I actually thought of that. But i'm betting the OP also has a couple of Selects before doing the insert.

Comment: Thanks for your help.  Yeah I am mainly doing inserts but I have a couple of simple selects beforehand so I'm going to add indexes on the fields in the where clauses.  Also going to take a look at what indices I have on the tables I'm inserting into

Comment: @Pattle Let us know if this was your solution.